# image as column separator

Tags: multicol, multicolumn, wrapfigure, posters

I'm writing a scientific poster in a 3 columns format (`\multicols*{3}`). I have two very tall and narrow images that I would like to use as column separators.

I would like to know if there is a proper way of doing it with the multicol package. Right know I'm doing it by using no ruler separator, and putting a wrapfigure in two of the columns, but i works only sometimes, and when it fails I don't understand why.

Thank you

Comment: this is easy enough if the columns are full height but a bit trickier on the first or last page where the balanced columns may be short, you would need to find the column height but then would you scale or crop the images to that height?

Comment: scale them, its a poster with a heading, and 3 colums below, where the text is. As separators I want to use the images, so I would scale them till the occupy the vercital space needed, however I don't know how to do it properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't tell Frank what I did to his code

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,graphicx}
\newdimen\imgh
\makeatletter
\def\columnseprulecolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule{%
\unskip
\setbox0\lastbox
\imgh=\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@\relax
\box\z@
\hss
\smash{\includegraphics[width=5pt, height=\imgh]{example-image}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\def\z{one two three four }
\def\zz{\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\par\z red yellow blue \z red yellow blue \z\z}
\def\zzz{\zz\z\zz\z\z\z\zz\zz\zz}

\zzz

\zzz

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

---

Or as requested in comments with two images

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,graphicx}
\setlength\columnsep{40pt}
\newdimen\imgh
\makeatletter
\def\columnseprulecolor\vrule\@width\columnseprule{%
\unskip
\setbox0\lastbox
\imgh=\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@\relax
\box\z@
\hss
\ifnum\count@<\mult@firstbox
\smash{\includegraphics[width=35pt, height=\imgh]{example-image-a}}%
\else
\smash{\includegraphics[width=35pt, height=\imgh]{example-image-b}}%
\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
\def\z{one two three four }
\def\zz{\z\z\z\z\z\z\z\par\z red yellow blue \z red yellow blue \z\z}
\def\zzz{\zz\z\zz\z\z\z\zz\zz\zz}

\zzz

\zzz

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your example, but I can't understand what you are doing :(

Comment: @ManuelPena the `\zzz` in the content of the multicols you can ignore, that just generates filler text (as you provided no example) the part it the preamble replaces the column separator rule by `\includegraphics[width=5pt, height=\imgh]{example-image}` so replace that image name by the image you want to use

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand know, but the point is that I have 2 different images that I want to use as first ruler and second ruler. I understand that my question wasn't clear, sorry.

Comment: @ManuelPena updated answer:-)

Comment: thank you very much, It works flawlessly, (in the next weeks I'll try to understand each command you used)